# A few errors that i have questions about for my Bank Account Form

Tags: c#

Hey guys I dabbled in OOP before with java in a previous class I took. I'm making a bank account form in C#. I'm taking a little bit at a time so I can learn from my mistakes and errors. I have my program file and my Account file. I commented where I have the errors and what they say in my program file and will post them down below. Thank you for taking the time to help me out

UPDATE THIS IS MY UPDATED CODE:

namespace BankAccountBank 
        {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private static void Bank(string[] args) 

    {

        // Create a list of accounts

        var accounts = new List<Account>

        {

            new Account("Dopey", 500),  //just put these accounts as a place holder

            new Account("Sleepy"),

            new Account("Sneezy", 300)
        };
        // Write these records to a file


        WriteFile(accounts); //I still don't see a text file after running this
    }

    private static void WriteFile(List<Account> accounts)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Submitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double x;


        if (OpenRdo.Checked == true && Nametxtbx.TextLength > 0)
        {
            double.TryParse(Nametxtbx.Text, out x);
            MessageBox.Show("Account Created", "Create Account", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Nametxtbx.Text = Name; // should it be acctName?

            Random acct = new Random();
            int AccountNumber = acct.Next(5, 1000);// after running and clicking the button there no number  it says system.random
            outputlbl.Text = acct.ToString();
        }




        void WriteFile(List<Account> accts) //"static is not valid for this item" what other item can i put here then?

        {

            StreamWriter outputFile = File.CreateText("accounts.txt");

            string record;

            foreach (var acct in accts)

            {

                record = $"{acct.Name},{acct.Balance}";

                Console.WriteLine($"Writing record: {record}");

                outputFile.WriteLine(record);

            }

            outputFile.Close();

        }
```

}

Account FIle:

```
namespace BankAccountBank
{
class Account
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public decimal Balance { get; private set; }

    public Account(string acctName, decimal acctBalance = 0)

    {
        Name = acctName;
        Balance = acctBalance;
    }

    public void Deposit(decimal amt)
    {
        Balance += amt;
    }

    public void Withdraw(decimal amt)
    {

        if (Balance - amt >= 0)
            Balance -= amt;

        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Can't withdraw more than balance");

    }

    override public string ToString()
    {
        return $"Account: {Name} / Balance = {Balance:C}";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check if you have another file in your project, possibly named `program.cs`. There you have _another_ main.

Comment: Is your WriteFile call inside a click method?  Fix your open and close brackets.

Comment: Please format your code WITHOUT all those blank lines and WITH real indentation.

Comment: There is a program.cs file that is the "entry point for the program" how do I change that? WriteFile is in the first static main

Comment: vs studio generated a main for you in program.cs. YOu should not add another one

Answer (score 0):

`Main` is responsible for being the entry point of your program. In particular, it *displays that first form*. It really shouldn't be part of `Form1`. Name the method there something else.

- If you need that function to run on startup, it can be invoked from `Form1`'s constructor, or in a handler for the `Loaded` event.
- `WriteFile` is all messed up because it is defined *inside another method*. Method's shouldn't (you technically *can* as of C#7) do that (except for anonymous or "lambda" methods). Get it into the class scope and it will be fine
- Also get rid of those `static` members. Until you *really* know what you are doing just avoiding `static` (except for `Main` where it is required) is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: About the second point, C# 7 added the concept of [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) that are nothing more that methods inside other methods. Some modifiers, like `static` aren't allowed, but otherwise they behave like any other method within that scope. Wheter or not is a good idea to use them is another history...........

Comment: @Alejandro Good point, added. I'm going to take the side of "not a good idea" though :D